Winform App to UWP App System.Data.SQLite error

Hi everyone. Hoping someone can help me and thank you to anyone that tries.
I have a WinForm app that I'm using in a Windows Application Packaging Project (Creates MSIX packages for distribution in Microsoft Store).
WinForm app is in C# using .NET 4.6 and compiles without errors, runs as expected.
When I run the UWP package, it installs but I get an error when I run it referring to System.Data.SQLite and I'm not sure why.
In both projects (WinForm App and UWP package) I have it set to Any CPU, but I think there is a 32/64 bit problem. Has anyone had this problem before and how can I fix it?
Full Error message:
The error details are as follows:
See the end of this message for details on invoking
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
************** Exception Text **************
System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
at System.Data.SQLite.UnsafeNativeMethods.sqlite3_config_none(SQLiteConfigOpsEnum op)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.StaticIsInitialized()
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteLog.PrivateInitialize(String className)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteLog.Initialize(String className)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String connectionString, Boolean parseViaFramework)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
at MyApp.FRMGetMyFunction.CMDGetMyFunction_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.8.9277.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_B
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll

MyApp
Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 1.1.44.0
CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/58250MyCompany.FWMyAppPro_1.1.44.0_neutral__f0fg3kf9fk41a/MyApp/MyApp.exe

System.Windows.Forms
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.8.9251.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_C
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll

System
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.8.9261.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_C
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll

System.Drawing
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.8.9037.0 built by: NET481REL1
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll

System.Configuration
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.8.9037.0 built by: NET481REL1
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll

System.Core
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.8.9277.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_B
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll

System.Xml
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.8.9037.0 built by: NET481REL1
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll

Accessibility
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.8.9037.0 built by: NET481REL1
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll

System.Data.SQLite
Assembly Version: 1.0.119.0
Win32 Version: 1.0.119.0
CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/58250MyCompany.FWMyAppPro_1.1.44.0_neutral__f0fg3kf9fk41a/MyApp/System.Data.SQLite.DLL

System.Data
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.8.9214.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_B
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll

System.Transactions
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.8.9037.0 built by: NET481REL1
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.
For example:
<system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
Edit:
Updated the project as you suggested, but I'm still getting the same error.
I have cleaned both projects and rebuilt each.


Yes, that's the problem.  Right now you run in 32-bit mode and your package probably contains the 64-bit version of the native SQLite dll.  Project > Properties > Build tab, select the Release configuration.  Select Any CPU as the platform target and untick Prefer 32-bit.

Hi Hans. Thanks for the response. Did as you said and I'm still getting the same result. Any other thoughts or ideas?

"We recommend that you use either the Entity Framework Core or the open-source SQLite library built by Microsoft." (for an abstraction layer in UWP) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases

Worked out the issue. Included a reference to a 32 bit SQLite.Interop.dll. Also, SQLite.Interop.dll was wasn't getting added in the build. Added x64 and x86 folders in teh base of my project. Included x64\SQLite.Interop.dll and x86\SQLite.Interop.dll in my project and setting to always copy for both DLLs fixed the issue. Hope that helps anyone that comes across the same issue. Thanks you everyone for your help and suggestions.

Worked out the issue. Included a reference to a 32 bit SQLite.Interop.dll. Also, SQLite.Interop.dll was wasn't getting added in the build. Added x64 and x86 folders in teh base of my project. Included x64\SQLite.Interop.dll and x86\SQLite.Interop.dll in my project and setting to always copy for both DLLs fixed the issue. Hope that helps anyone that comes across the same issue. Thanks you everyone for your help and suggestions.
